# Change my Settings language

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, nslocalizedstring

I'm now translating my app. I've already translated every view and data inside the app but I've also some settings for the app in the Settings menu of the iPad. All of them are in Spanish and I would like to translate them depending of the language set on my app (or set at system settings, never mind). I'm attaching a little screenshot of my settings Screen. 
How can I translate it?

[image: Settings Screen]

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but seems like it doesn't upload any picture

Comment: try localization. basically you store different translations of your strings in a file and the os uses the one that belongs to the selected language

Comment: I've a differrent .strings file for each language and I've all my labels on them. I've changed serveral times the language of my iPad but it always load the Spanish labels

Comment: Ok, I did it. I don't know why but my first .strings file was not working. I've just created a new one, set all labels and it's working. Thanks!